# What version of .NET MVC can I run in VS 2010?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am forced to use VS 2010 on a project.

What is the highest version of ASP.NET MVC that I can use?

Answer (score 2):

The highest version that VS2010 can use is ASP.NET MVC 4.

For more information see...
http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4 and http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc5

You must have at least VS2012 in order to use MVC 5.